# Is Fermat's Last Theorem really proven by Prof. Wiles?

Tags: set-theory

The Prof. Wiles uses axioms, postulates and assumptions of the Set Theory. They can not be proven, thus, the Fermat's Last Theorem is not rigorously proven, but only confirmed by Set Theory? Source of worry:

Colin McLarty. What does it take to prove Fermat's last theorem? Grothendieck and the logic of number theory // Bulletin of Symbolic Logic. 2010. Vol.16, Number 3, 359-377.

Comment: If you don't want to assume any logic theory whose consistency is sloppy then you won't be able to prove there are infinitely many primes

Comment: I don't think there's cause to pile on the downvotes... this question is founded on some misconceptions, but I think deserves the presumption of good faith.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood something; it's true that Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem uses an axiom (existence of an uncountable Grothendieck universe) which is independent of ZFC (the usual axioms for set theory) - but it's generally thought that this is convenient rather than an essential part of the proof. This is separate from the more philosophical question of what it means to prove stuff anyways.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. May be some people think it is a troll (and they may be right). However using some axioms or not is a huge topic for a lot of people, you cannot sweep the problem away. @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: Every proof in math (and everywhere) uses axioms. Nothing can be "proved from nothing".

Answer (score 13):

You can't prove anything without assumptions and **a proof that uses set theory (correctly) is considered rigorous by modern mathematical standards.**

But there are a few things to think about here.

First, the proof has not been formalized (i.e. written down in a computer-checkable way). This is par for the course for modern mathematics and not considered problematic by most people... it is [a lot of hard work](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00816699/document) to formalize an elaborate proof and generally mathematicians are content to pore over the details and convince themselves that the reasoning of every step is sound.

This does however open up the question of whether we know precisely which set theoretical axioms it would take to formalize the proof. For instance, can it be done in ZFC, or does it require some [mild large cardinal assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe)? Many mathematicians would accept it either way, although some are uncomfortable with assuming large cardinals. In any event it's something to think about, and suggests some directions for further research. This is generally what the paper you cite is exploring, and he seems to indicate that the consensus is that it is formalizable in ZFC.

(I doubt McLarty is skeptical of the proof in any sense. At the very least, on a quick skim, that doesn't seem to be the point of the paper.)

Another concern touched on in the paper is that the theorem certainly doesn't require any set theoretical assumptions to state, so shouldn't there be a more elementary proof that doesn't need set theory? Well, perhaps there should, but one wasn't discovered in hundreds of years... discovery of an elementary proof would certainly be considered a major achievement, even many years after the theorem is accepted as fact.

But perhaps sometimes big ideas are needed to prove simple things. (However, see [Friedman's Grand Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic#Friedman's_grand_conjecture).) Also, case of the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) might give some perspective here too: an elementary proof was found years after the original non-elementary proof, and although it is considered a major achievement, it was much less enlightening than the original and substantially fewer people bother to learn it today.

I don't any of these issues are as important as the possibility that the proof is simply wrong and the error has just not been discovered yet. It's a long and complicated proof, and it's not unheard of for errors in big important proofs to be discovered years after the fact (though I don't know offhand of any cases where the error turned out to not be fixable). In fact, there was a major error in Wiles' original proof, though this was found and fixed relatively quickly.

However, it's probably pretty unlikely that an error remains after 25 years cause of how well-studied the proof is, but I think it's still more likely than mathematicians deciding set theoretical methods used are unsound, e.g. if it were discovered that ZFC plus Grothendieck universe is inconsistent and that the proof can't be done in a consistent fragment. (At least the former is more likely in this lifetime - there could be a major sea change in methodology down the line.)

Comment: For those who are interested : it took a year to fix Wiles's mistake.